# Does Java7's multiple-exception catch clause use duck typing?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#multiple

> A catch block that handles multiple exception types creates no duplication in the bytecode generated by the compiler; the bytecode has no replication of exception handlers.

What if the code looks like this:

```
class FooExcn extends Exception { ... }
class BarExcn extends Exception { ... }
class Fred {
  void log(FooExcn f) { /* calls FooExcn-specific methods */ }
  void log(BarExcn b) { /* calls BarExcn-specific methods */ }
  void test() {
    try { }
    catch (FooExcn | BarExcn ex) {
      log(ex);
      /* do other stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like the bytecode for the catch block depends on the type of exception, so would have to be duplicated, once for each excn type caught.

Comment: I am not sure the text you quote implies duck typing?

Comment: The code doesn't compile: therefore not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java 7 (Platform) have support for [dynamic dispatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html#invokedynamic), for other languages running on JVM such as [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) or [JRuby](http://jruby.org/). However the code above doesn't work on Java 7

```
test.java:9: error: no suitable method found for log(Exception)
      log(ex);
      ^
    method Fred.log(BarExcn) is not applicable
      (actual argument Exception cannot be converted to BarExcn by method invocation conversion)
    method Fred.log(FooExcn) is not applicable
      (actual argument Exception cannot be converted to FooExcn by method invocation conversion)
1 error
```

So yes - duck typing can and is run on JVM (even before 1.7 as they used different techniques then `invokedynamic`) but it looks like the code above is just using the least general common type.